# AppleScript - how to search a list for items containing numbers

Tags: applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript which contains a list of items that are mixed between text and numbers. I'd like to filter this list to only the items containing numbers.

I haven't been able to figure this out on my own and so far haven't been able to find any helpful suggestions online.

Here's my list:

```
{"table", "s01e01", "nam", "aces", "linear", "20160430", "01", "textless", "3840x2160", "000011", "jpg"}
```

And I only want the search to return these:

```
{"s01e01", "20160430", "01", "3840x2160", "000011"}
```

For the sake of this post, let's say the list is stored in myList.

I've tried:

```
set numberItems to items of myList which contain integers
```

but that's a big no go!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a terribly efficient way to do it, but I think that's an AppleScript issue rather than my lack of creativity (I might be wrong):

```
    set mylist to {"table", "s01e01", "nam", "aces", "linear", "20160430", "01", "textless", "3840x2160", "000011", "jpg"}

    repeat with str in mylist
        set str to the contents of str

        repeat with i from 0 to 9
            if str contains i then
                set end of mylist to str
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat

        set mylist to the rest of mylist
    end repeat

    return mylist
```

You could do it much more gracefully using a bit of shell script:

```
    set mylist to {"table", "s01e01", "nam", "aces", "linear", "20160430", "01", "textless", "3840x2160", "000011", "jpg"}

    set the text item delimiters to space

    do shell script "grep -o '\\S*\\d\\S*' <<< " & the quoted form of (mylist as text)

    return the paragraphs of the result
```

**EDIT:** I spoke a little too soon about my (lack of creativity), as I just came up with this slightly slicker method of doing it with AppleScript.  In theory, it should be faster than the first method too:

```
    set mylist to {"table", "s01e01", "nam", "aces", "linear", "20160430", "01", "textless", "3840x2160", "000011", "jpg"}

    set the text item delimiters to {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    repeat with str in mylist
        set str to the contents of str as text

        if str ≠ the text items of str as text then ¬
            set the end of mylist to str

        set mylist to the rest of mylist
    end repeat

    return mylist
```